# Create a DocumentDB post type trigger to store document edit history

Tags: triggers, azure-cosmosdb

I want to create a post trigger to save the old content to another document when someone modifying a document. I really didn't find a lot of sample codes about DocumentDB triggers on Internet so I hope I can get some help here...

If in SQL Server, I would create a After trigger on UPDATE and use Inserted and Deleted temp tables to track table modification history.

For example, in SQL it would be

```
Insert Into TableToStoreHistory
Select {some columns} From inserted i JOIN deleted d
ON i.id = d.id
```

I know in DocumentDB, the java script code will be totally different. I wish I could come up with some code first by myself. However, I didn't find one closer example showing how to do this in DocumentDB post trigger.

Let's say my document is defined like below:

Document A

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "content": "Hello World!"
}
```

And I want the post trigger write into another document when someone modify Document A. The old content will be written into Document B maybe like below

```
{
    "id": {assign some other id maybe "1_date&time"},
    "oldContent": "HelloWorld"
}
```

Can anyone help, please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by borrowing Shireesh's idea.

To save the old content into another document, you need a pre-trigger and you need to query the document before actual Replace action happens. Below is my code:

```
function ResourceAuditHistory() {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
var doc = getContext().getRequest().getBody();

var ts = new Date();
var time = ts.getTime().toString();
var idNew = doc.id + time;

var Query = 'SELECT * From c Where c.id = "' + doc.id +'"';

var accept = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), Query, updateMetadataCallback);

function updateMetadataCallback(err, documents, responseOptions) {
    if (err) throw new Error("Error" + err.message);
    if (documents.length != 1) throw 'Unable to find metadata document';

    var oldDoc = documents[0];

    var historyDoc =
        {
            "id": idNew,
            "Content": oldDoc.Content
        };
    collection.createDocument(collectionLink, historyDoc, function (err, docCreated) {
        if (err) { throw new Error('Error: ' + err.message); }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best discussion and examples for triggers that I know of can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/

I suggest reading it all, but you can skip to the section on "Database Triggers" to look at an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Pre-trigger that takes the incoming request body and insert the additional document like the one shown below

```
function() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var doc = getContext().getRequest().getBody();

    var ts = new Date();
    var time = ts.getTime().toString();
    var idNew = doc.id + time;
    var newDoc = { id: idNew, oldContent: doc.content };
    collection.createDocument(collection.getSelfLink(), newDoc, function(err, docCreated) {
        if(err) { throw new Error('Error: ' + err.message); } \r\n"
    });
}
```

This trigger should be run as part of the update requests.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Your approach is saving the new content to another document because the doc = getContenxt().getRequest().getBody is always the content to be write into DocDB. However, I want to save the old content. You gave me the idea how to solve my issue. I will post my solution below. Thanks!